# Flutter app keeps crashing when its build for arm64

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, cocoapods

I have been working on a flutter app. Everything works fine on android and ios simulator, but when i try to upload the app to TestFlight it doesn't work the app crashes on launch.

I have tried building the app in xcode (crashes on launch when uploaded) and i have build it by using the command `flutter build ipa --release` same thing happens. I have no idea how to proceed. Does anyone have an idea?

I get this as a crash report:

> FirebaseFirestoreInternal: firebase::firestore::util::ObjcThrowHandler(firebase::firestore::util::ExceptionType, char const*, char const*, int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator<ch... + 108

These are my dependencies for the project:

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

  #Firebase
  firebase_core: ^2.25.5
  firebase_auth: ^4.17.6
  cloud_firestore: ^4.15.6
  firebase_storage: ^11.6.7
  firebase_database: ^10.4.7
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.2

  #Animation
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.7.0
  animations: ^2.0.11
  flutter_staggered_animations: ^1.0.0
  awesome_dialog: ^3.0.2
  animated_digit: ^3.2.3
  animated_number: ^1.0.2
  animated_flip_counter: ^0.2.6

  #Premission
  intl: ^0.18.1
  permission_handler: ^10.2.0
  path: ^1.8.1
  provider: ^6.0.2
  image_picker: ^0.8.5+3

  #Toast
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.9

  #Fonts
  google_fonts: ^4.0.4
```

I have tried removing the pod files and installing them again, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. For some reason my app got built with push notifications and due to that I never declared it in xcode wich lead to the app crashing on launch. I fixed it in xcode by adding runner -> signing and capabilities -> capability -> push notification

Still dont know why my project added push notification tho.